# ASP.NET Friendly URLs 404 errors on IIS Application

Tags: asp.net

I'm using ASP.NET Friendly URLs in my web application project.

It works without any problem, but when I use IIS and Create Application under my default web site I get **404 error**.

For example I have a page with URL address like this:

```
localhost/home/default.aspx
```

and I rewrite it to this address:

```
localhost/home/
```

with this line in **routeconfig.cs**:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("home", "home", "~/home/Default.aspx")
```

I refer to this new URL in my link by `href="/home"` and as I said it works ok until I use the application under IIS.

I created the application under my default web site in IIS with name **APP1** and when I click on link with `href="/home"` my page address must be `localhost/APP1/home` but the address in address bar changes to `localhost/home` and I get `404 error`.

Could you help me solve this problem?

Comment: Does the "default web site" of IIS have it's own application/settings? Does your app have the correct version of ASP.Net set? What happens if you request the actual `aspx` file? What happens if you create a new site/application in IIS (not under `default`)?

Answer (score 0):

The home page will not be localhost/app1/home - that's not how it works.

*1* - Create an entry in your hosts file: -

127.0.0.1 app1

*2* - Create a new website in IIS, pointing at the root folder of your website. Make sure you enter 'app1' into the 'Host name' field: -

[image: creating the new site in IIS]

*3* - The home page of your new site is **http://app1/home**